# Error starting Django with Pinax

Tags: python, django, pinax

Upon trying to start a Pinax app, I receive the following error:

```
Error: No module named notification
```

Below are the steps I took

```
svn co http://svn.pinaxproject.com/pinax/trunk/ pinax 
cd pinax/pinax/projects/basic_project
./manage.py syncdb
```

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:**

Turns out there are some bugs in the SVN version. Downloading the latest release solved my problem. If any one has any other suggestions on getting the trunk working, they would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd avoid the svn version all together. It's unmaintained and out of date. Instead, use the git version at http://github.com/pinax/pinax or (even better) the recently release 0.7b3 downloadable from http://pinaxproject.com

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure where I got the idea to download the SVN version…

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:
1. Check all of your imports to make sure that notification is getting into the namespace.
2. You may be missing quotes around an import path (eg. in your urls.py: (r'^test', 'mysite.notification') -- sometimes I forget the quotes around the view)

Comment: My problem is that while I'm ok with Python, I'm not too familiar with Django or Pinax. This was supposed to work out of the box. I'll poke around and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the latest install instructions here:

http://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/600d6c5ca0b45814bdc73b1264d28bb66c661ac8/INSTALL

Don't think this will work on Windows (maybe if you are using cygwin) as they are using virtualenv and pip.

Note the version has recently been upgraded to 0.7rc1

IIRC I had to add a directory or two to the Python path last time I did a fresh install of Pinax. I'm doing a fresh checkout now into a new virtualenv, I'll edit this answer if I hit any snags.